# Which is the easiest game in Prince of Persia series?

Tags: prince-of-persia

At present, I am playing Prince of Persia: Sands of Time. After 69% completion, I find that it is way too difficult, even though I use cheats(meaning infinite sand, infinite power, and infinite walking on walls). It seems impossible for me to go ahead.

Please suggest to me the easiest game in the POP series.

Comment: Heh, I suggest you *don't* try the original game [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game) ) if you find the modern remakes too hard! (kids today, grumble grumble grumble...)

Comment: [Fixed link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game%29)

Comment: @therefromhere: ihave played original one and complete tht :D

Comment: This question seems completely subjective to me.  What is "easy" for one person is hard for another.

Comment: @sjohnston: easiest not easy. lolz :D

Comment: @sjohnston I don't agree that this question is completely subjective, but I do think it's too subjective for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am currently enjoying playing the [2008 Prince of Persia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(2008_video_game)) game on the Xbox 360 (but its also available on PS3 and PC).

It is relatively easy so far and quite a few [reviews for the game suggest this too](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/prince-of-persia)

Comment: Just to add to the anwser: What makes 2008 Prince of Persia so easy is that you quite literally can not die in the game, as Elika, your companion, will always save you, no matter if you jumped into a bottomless pit or are fighting against an evil foe. I consider Sands of Time to be a better and more interesting game, but the 2008 PoP is certainly a very relaxing and enjoyable game on its own.

Comment: While the platforming for 2008 Prince is easy, the fights get kind of crazy about halfway through (boss fights, that is).

Answer (score 1):

If this is about Ubisoft's Prince of Persia Game Series, Sands of Time is the easiest of all. Honestly, I also found it to be hard when I'm playing it for the first time. The following will be hard

- Finding the way
- Solving the puzzles
- Very tiring and long fights

Finding the way

Unlike other games, the game doesn't suggest any directions, we have to find on our own. This makes the game hard as well as challenging. It's hard in the beginning, but you'll love it once cracked.

Solving the Puzzles

I wasted days to solve a few puzzles, especially the one with mirrors and the other one with many doors. The mirrors puzzle, when I solved it first, I didn't even know how I did it. While doing it the second time, I observed clearly how I did it.

Very tiring and long fights

The first one of this kind is when the Prince has to kill his own father. Prince is surrounded by many enemies at once. I planned to quit playing this game to avoid facing this. The key to win this is `not to stay at one place for longer time`. Just jump over enemies, hit them; roll over the floor to escape, etc. But, never stay on the same ground until you get killed. Also, learn how to block the enemies swords. This is more useful.

Don't give up on this game. For me, this is the best of the games I've played. The story and the game play are so gripping. Believe me, you'll enjoy the story more in the next parts.

Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 0):

The Two Thrones is the easiest of all POP series games. I ve completed it 18 times totally. (including PS2, PC, and laptop) :)